# Create A Maximum-Gradient Vector Overlay QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, overlay

I have generated [several vector layers](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByD7wF-aT-H1Q2dNTVBEd0tFNFU/view?usp=sharing) of different gradients and geographic areas (PUMAs, ZCTAs & Census Tracts).

Is there a way I can overlay all these layers with the aim of identifying the ultimate hotspots?

Data merge won't do the trick.

Comment: Have you considered converting them to rasters and applying some map algebra to get the hotspots? That's usually efficient and quicker to compute than vector analysis.